# Using WebDriverJS promise outside webdriver context

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, promise

I am trying to use [WebDriverJS](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Promises) promise outside Webdriver context. I have a utility that can start a proxy, set custom header, stop the proxy etc. I want to start and set custom headers before I  launch the browser (before webdriver is initialized). All the methods in the utility return a promise from WebdriverJS. Here is the code,

```
BrowserProxy.prototype = {
'start': function () {
        var d = webdriver.promise.defer();
        someAsync(
          //here promise is either fulfilled or rejected;
          //d.reject(err) or d.fulfill();
        );
        return d;
 },
 'setHeaders': function () {
    //similar stuff like start method
 },
 'stop': function () {
    //similar stuff like start method
 }
}
```

outside this file, I am doing below, however all proxy method get executed before the browser launches.

```
browserProxy.start();
//initialize driver
browserProxy.setHeaders();
driver.get('http://www.google.com);
browserProxy.stop();
```

However if I chain the calls in `then` methods, flow of methods is expected. I am not sure why. Can someone help?

Comment: That is how promises are supposed to work.  When you chain them with 'thens', execution of the next function only occurs when the previous has resolved or rejected.  If you just call them one after another, each function will execute immediately.

Comment: According to WebDriverJS promise documentation, tasks would run one after the other because they are pushed onto a queue and promise manager maintains a queue of scheduled tasks, executing each once the one before it in the queue is finished . Note that `driver.get` also returns a promise in the code I mentioned. Since all of the methods in the code block return promises, I expect them to run in the order

Comment: That's not true. Look at their control flows docs where they explain promises in detail- https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Control_Flows

Comment: You are right, sorry.

Comment: Did you try using webdriver.promise.createflow?  It isn't exactly what you want to do but I am curious if it would work.

Comment: Yeah i tried but that didn't work either

Comment: Does the btowserproxy.stop method wait until driver.get returns?  It seems like their promise handling mechanism is initialized in driver.get.  I bet if you then the first two until driver.get it may work as expected after that.

Comment: Stop method returns webdriver.promise similar to driver.get. but i think your guess is right, promise manager is probably initialized in driver.get. should check their source code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is: Selenium "Control Flow". The control flow wraps all calls to selenium API as stated here: [Control Flow](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Control_Flows).

If you want to execute "in order" (sync) some "async" task inside selenium context, you should add it to the master control flow. (note that you can create custom flows also)

Your code should look like this:

```js
BrowserProxy.prototype = {
'start': function () {
        var flow = webdriver.promise.controlFlow();
        flow.execute(function(){
            var aPromiseToResolveWhenAsyncTaskEnds = webdriver.promise.defer();
            doAnAsyncTask().then(function(){
               aPromiseToResolveWhenAsyncTaskEnds.fulfill();
            });
            return aPromiseToResolveWhenAsyncTaskEnds.promise;
          });
 },
 'setHeaders': function () {
    //similar stuff like start method
 },
 'stop': function () {
    //similar stuff like start method
 }
}
```

Comment: Works great. The only thing I had to change in your example code was to return deferred object in `start` function rather than within the control flow functio. Thanks!